# error: called object '0' is not a function

Tags: c

I'm running into the following error in both functions in the following code:

```
In function 'Celsius_Converter':
Line 64: error: called object '0' is not a function
In function 'Fahrenheit_Converter':
Line 90: error: called object '1' is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 3
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: Convert either Celsius to Fahrenheit, or Fahrenheit to Celsius.
 *
 * Input: Celsius or Fahrenheit Temperature
 *
 * Output: Fahrenheit or Celsius, depending on which one the User requested.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)                     
{
//Local Declarations
char choice;
int fahrenheit;
int celsius;


//Statements
printf("This program converts Celsius temperature to Fahrenheit degree and     Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius degree. \n");
printf("If you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, please enter C.");
printf("If you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter F.");
scanf("%s", &choice);

//Process
if (choice == 'C') {
fahrenheit = Celsius_Converter();
printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit degree is %d", &fahrenheit);
}

else {
celsius = Fahreinheit_Converter();
printf("The temperature in Celsius degree is %d", &celsius);
}


return 0;
} // End main


/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 3
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
 *
 * Input: Celsius Temperature
 *
 * Output: Fahrenheit
 */
int Celsius_Converter ()
{
//Local Declarations
double fahrenheit;
double celsius;

printf("Enter a temperature in Celsius.");
scanf("%d", &fahrenheit);
celsius = (5/9) (&fahrenheit - 32);
return celsius;
} //end Celsius_Converter
```

```
/* 
 *Program Name: COP 2220-10018 Project 3
 *
 * Author: Nathan Gamble
 * 
 * Description: Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
 *
 * Input: Fahrenheit Temperature
 *
 * Output: Celsius
 */
 int Fahrenheit_Converter ()
{
//Local Declarations
double fahrenheit;
double celsius;

printf("Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit.");
scanf("%d", &celsius);
fahrenheit = (9/5) (&celsius + 32);
return fahrenheit;
} //end Fahrenheit_Converter
```

Comment: A piece of advice: almost all your comments only make your program less readable. Remove those comments, clear code is always better than using comments.

Comment: If you're asking for answers online, you might not want to include your name and the course name in the post.

Comment: :( I answered this and then thought "hmm, this is an interesting problem,  I wonder if anyone's run into it before."  And there's an almost exact duplicate, right down to the Fahrenheit/Celsius conversion.  @LinkNoneya, you should have been able to find that duplicate by searching for the error message.  That wouldn't have covered the address/value issue, but it would have found the main issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You're using the *address* of some values instead of the values theselves.  You use the address of `celsius` when you call `scanf` (which is right, because `scanf` needs to know where to *store* the value):

   ```
   double celsius;
   scanf("%d", &celsius);
   ```

   but you need to `celsius` itself when you do arithmetic, not its address:

   ```
   fahrenheit = (9/5) (celsius + 32); // instead of &celsius
   ```

   There's a similar error in the other conversion routine, where you use `&fahrenheit` rather than `fahrenheit`.  This is also an issue in your output.  When you're printing, you need to use the *value* of the variable, not its address.  So

   ```
   printf("The temperature in Celsius degree is %d", &celsius);
   ```

   should also use `celsius`, not `&celsius`.
2. Once you've got those worked out, though, you can address your main issue.

   ```
   something (...)
   ```

   is function call syntax in C. This means that when you do, e.g., `(9/5)(celsius + 32)`, you're trying to call a function `(9/5)`, which is, by integer arithmetic, `0`.  So, you need to make the multiplication explicit, using `*`, so you'd have

   ```
   (9/5)*(celsius+32)
   ```

   but then you'll still run into the problem that `9/5` is `1`, because it's integer arithmetic.  You can fix this by making at least one of those numbers a non-integer, e.g., by using `(9/5.0)`:

   ```
   fahrenheit = (9/5.0) * (celsius + 32);
   ```

   A similar explanation holds for the other case, except that `5/9` is `0`.
3. The return types of some of your methods aren't right.  E.g., since you're trying to return a `double`, the function needs to be declared to return a `double`, not an `int`.

   ```
   int Celsius_Converter () // needs to be double
   {
   double celsius;
   ...
   celsius = (5/9) (&fahrenheit - 32);
   return celsius;
   } //end Celsius_Converter
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about using * for multiplication.

Program looks to be working now (After I fixed a misspelling of fahrenheit).

Comment: There are some other issues, too, though…  I've updated my answer for some of them, but I won't guarantee that that's all of them.

Answer (score 0):

First, the answer to your question:

`(9/5) (&celsius + 32)` is a function invocation, more precisely, you are trying to invoke the function 9/5, which is 1, passing &celsius + 32 (which is an error) as its parameter.
What you want to do is probably `(9/5) * (&celsius + 32)`. There is no such thing as implicit operators in C. Actually, it should be `(9/5) * (celsius + 32)`: the & is wrong here.
The same goes for the other function.

Then, some other considerations on your code:

1. `scanf("%s", &choice);` is a hazard, because you are asking for buffer overruns. You'd better do `scanf("%c", &choice);` or

   ```
   char choice[2];
   ...
   scanf("%1s", choice);
   ```
2. `printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit degree is %d", &fahrenheit);` is wrong. It should be `printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit degree is %d", fahrenheit);`. The same goes for Celsius. The & is needed for `scanf`s, when you're reading into a primitive type (you'll learn the reason behind this as you go further with your studies, or you can post another question, or check a online C guide).

Moreover, I have some doubts on the rationale behind your decomposition in functions, but, again, this is something you don't learn now.